# slimScroll is not defined on Browser Back Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

I have a basic code that uses the jquery.slimscroll, which works perfectly fine on page load. But if I navigate to an inner page and try to go back using the "back" button on browser, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slimScroll'

I have checked the element's **length** and confirmed that the object exists. My jQuert is as simple as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#boxsrchome").slimScroll();
</script>
```

Note: I tried wrapping the code around **$(document).ready()** and **$(window).load()**. And that did not help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, see if jQuery is defined by inputting jQuery in the console. If it is, try this:
Try wrapping it in:

```
(function($) {
    $("#boxsrchome").slimScroll();
})(jQuery);
```

If it isn't, you have a problem with the way you're including your files. Also, make sure you aren't including slimscroll.js in the wrong place, and make sure you're not redefining the jQuery object by using `jQuery.noConflict();` anywhere, although, that shouldn't matter with this method.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Alain! I should go learn more about the '$' as function argument.

Comment: The reason why this works is you're passing the jQuery object as an argument, and defining $ to be used inside your function as $ = jQuery;. The problem is that $ is probably not defined, either because you're using noConflict, or for some other reason. Consider going through your code to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like the browser cannot load your `slimScroll` plugin due to wrong path of your file or wrong file name. Try to use `firebug` or chrome developer tools to check if your file are loaded properly.

You can also try to use direct link from Github, so your code should look like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/master/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#boxsrchome").slimScroll();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps and it will work definitely.

1.use this npm: `npm install jquery-slimscroll`

2.Update Your **.angular-cli.json** file with below code

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"
      ],
```

3.html Structure

```
<div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur .... snip</p>
</div>
```

4.Use following slimscroll

```
$('#content').slimScroll({
        height: '250px',
        color:'#F44336'
    });
```